# ValueEventListener read only one layer

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist

I have a Firebase database and I am using `addValueEventListener` to populate an `ArrayList` which is then displayed in a `RecyclerView` however I want the `ArrayList` to be populated with only one layer of the data and not the embedded data in another branch. Here is an example of how the database could look like:

[image]

The desired outcome is that my `RecyclerView` will be populated with the objects that is the content of branch `a` but the current outcome is that it is also being populated with the object `b` as one object with the children of it as values, I want only the values of branch `a` in my list. Is this possible, if so, how?

Code:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        list.clear();
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            Object value = snapshot.getValue();
            if (value != null)
            {
                list.add(new Task(value.toString(), snapshot.getKey()));
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size() - 1);
            }
        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDK always loads complete nodes from the Realtime Database.

There is no way to get `a` without also getting `b` in your current data model. In your code you can exclude `b` by looping over the children of your `snapshot` too, and check [if they have any children](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#hasChildren()).

If this is a common use-case for your app, consider changing your data structure, or adding an additional node where you only have `a`, to save bandwidth.